# Ajax return doesnt allow to focus on a select box which is getting populated from ajax

Tags: ajax, select, focus

I have a pair of select boxes, on selecting country from the select box, the state select box gets populated from an ajax query pertaining to that country.

But the focus is not getting shifted to the state select box, instead it goes to the top of the page.

Any help would be highly appreciated. :)

Answer (score 1):

If you are not using Jquery or any other object library, but just plain XMLHttpRequest, and your Ajax connection is synchronous, try this after receiving all data (after [XMLHttpRequest object].readyState which must be equals to 4, i.e. all data received):

```
setTimeout
(
  function()
  {
    if (field)
    {
      field.focus();
    }
  },

  200
);
```

Substitute 'field' by your combobox reference and '200' by any timeout in milliseconds that suits your needs.
Good luck.

Comment: Esteves Pereira : it seems to work in IE but fails for chrome and mozilla.

Comment: Can you post your code? I've used those coding over and over again with mozilla without any glitch...

Answer (score 0):

Try in your ajax response:

```
$('#yourStateSelect').select();
//or
setTimeout(function() { $('#yourStateSelect').select(); }, 100);
```

Comment: I think it is something about jquery.
i dunno much abt that...can you please tell something in javascript or php.